# Swift Collcetionview didSelectItemAtIndexPath not working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In myscenario, I am using `UICollectionView` in Storyboard. The `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` not working. I have added `Imageview` on UICollectionView and using customcell.

**CollectionView CustomCell**

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2
    }
}
```

**My CollectionView Delegates**

```
class ModernViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

        @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     collectionView.delegate = self
     collectionView.dataSource = self
     collectionView.allowsSelection = true
}
        // MARK: CollectionView Delegate
        func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return 1
       }

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return self.listData
       }

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
            let item = self.listData[indexPath.item]
            let url = item.profileimage
            cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url ?? "sample.png"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "sample.png"))
            return cell
       }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
           return CGSize(width: 35.0, height: 35.0)
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
            //let item = self.listData[indexPath.item]
            //print("SELECTED COLLECTION CELL: \(item.firstname ?? "")")
        }
}
```

Comment: Will you post entire collection view code.

Comment: @SureshMopidevi question updated

Comment: does your class confirms `UICollectionViewDelegate`?

Comment: @Mahendra Yes I gave `UICollectionViewDelegate`. Only did select not working

Comment: I mean...have you added `UICollectionViewDelegate` beside your view controller's name?

Comment: @Mahendra Yes I added.

Comment: Have you added TapGesture in that file?

Comment: @RushabhShah you mean for Imageview or custom cell. Sorry, I didn't added TapGesture. Could please provide me a code

Comment: I'm just asking you. So if you have not added then not an issue.

Comment: If your entire cell covered with image view. please check wether the imageView's `isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: @SureshMopidevi Yeah I checked in storyboard all Cell and image view isUserInteractionEnabled = true only

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from collectionViewCell class

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width
```

updated code

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        // self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2 // remove this line 
    }
}
```

I think you need to set cornerRadius of imageView instead of cell.

```
 self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/ 2
```

Comment: looks good, can you check the imageView user interaction is enable or disable?

Comment: yes I gave it. is it possible to add Tapgesture for cell. Imageview?

Comment: Have you set imageView user interaction enable true ?

Comment: is it possible to add Tapgesture for cell. -> Yes

Comment: yes I gave `cell.imageView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: try cell.imageView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

Comment: also remove this line : self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2

Comment: check collectionView isUserInteractionEnabled is enable?

Comment: Its also enabled

Comment: @iosdev just delete collectionViewCell UI and create again.

Comment: @iosdev also put all code whatever you used inside collectioViewCell and cellforRowAtItem.

Comment: Okey Thank you so much!

Comment: @iosdev have you check ?

Comment: Yes buddy I am reseting all constraints and trying to recreate. Nothing wrong in my code but I don't know why its not working. I am doubting on constraints.  I will update you here ASAP.